# How to fix? Triggers exception when trying to free dynamic allocated memory

Tags: c

This is my first time posting question, and I did try to find solution, but, even if I did found it I didn't recognize it.

So, as the title says, the problem is in this triggered exception "Exception thrown at 0x0F26372D (ucrtbased.dll) in lab10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCC4.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.", which happens when I step into line -> free(word).

This did happen to me a few times when I was learning malloc, but I overlooked it - thinking there was some other problem. But now I see that I'am doing something wrong.

The point of the program is - writing the struct "word". I need to input sentence and "cut" it into words, and then every word put in struct together with size of letters in the word and ordinal number of the word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word {
    char text_word[50];
    unsigned sizee; //number of letters of the word
    unsigned number; //ordinal number of the word
};

void cutting_sentence(struct word *p, char *sen) { //sen is sentence
    int size_sen, i, j;

    size_sen = strlen(sen) + 1; //size of sentence

    p = (struct word*)malloc(size_sen * sizeof(struct word)); 
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("\nNot enaugh memory!");
        return 0;
    }

    strcpy(p[0].text_word, strtok(sen, " ,.!?")); 
    p[0].sizee = strlen(p[0].text_word);
    p[0].number = 1;

    printf("word:%s \t size:%u \t ordinal number of the word:%u\n", 
        p[0].text_word, p[0].sizee, p[0].number);

    for (i = p[0].sizee - 1, j = 1;i < size_sen;++i) {
        if (*(sen + i) == ' ' || *(sen + i) == '.' || *(sen + i) == ','
        || *(sen + i) == '?' || *(sen + i) == '!') {
            strcpy(p[j].text_word, strtok(NULL, " ,.!?"));
            p[j].sizee = strlen(p[j].text_word);
            p[j].number = j + 1;

            printf("word:%s \t size:%u \t ordinal number of the 
                        word:%u\n", p[j].text_word, p[j].sizee, p[j].number);

            j++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char sentence[1024];
    struct word *word;

    printf("Sentence: ");
    gets(sentence);

    cutting_sentence(&word, sentence);

    free(word);  //here is exception triggered

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should complain about mismatching types... In the `main` function, what is the type of `word`? What is then the type of `&word`? And what is the type of the first argument to `cutting_sentence`? It seems you make an attempt to emulate pass-by-reference in C, but doesn't go all the way.

Comment: And never ***ever*** use the `gets` function! It's [a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that have even been removed from the C specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead (but be aware of its differences from `gets`).

Comment: word is the type -> struct word * , and when I try to pass it to the function without '&' it tells me it isn't initialized. Well, if I were to make struct word word[something]; then my passing to function would be ok? But then I have problem as I don't know many words I will have? 
Ok, so gets is out

Comment: The type of `words` is `struct word *`. Then the type of `&words` (being a pointer to `words`) must be `struct word **`. Not exactly what the function expects.

Comment: yes! They are entirely different types. Not linkable at all! Thank you! But do you maybe know how can I solve this problem:
Error tells me I need to use '->' but I cannot use that since I am using *p[j].sizee , I mean since I'am using dot '.'

Comment: That's a problem of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Inside the function, once you corrected the argument type, then the expression `*p[j].sizee` is actually equal to `(*p[j]).sizee`. I.e. it tries to dereference `p[j]` as a pointer, which it isn't. Instead you need to use explicit parentheses like `(*p)[j].sizee`.

Comment: Making matters even worse, neither `malloc` nor `free` are properly pulled into the namespace in the first place. This code has no `#include <stdlib.h>`.  If you remove the casts to `malloc` ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)) and the code pukes, doesn't compile, thats a phat clue you're doing something wrong.

Comment: regarding: `gets(sentence);`  the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and completely removed from the lastest versions of C.  Suggest using `fgets()`  (read the MAN page for details.

Comment: OT: regarding: `p = (struct word*)malloc(size_sen * sizeof(struct word));`  when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `struct word *word;`  It is a poor programming practice to name a variable the same as a struct name.  Suggest changing the pointer name to something unique

Comment: regarding: `void cutting_sentence(struct word *p, char *sen)`  the parameter 'p' (a terrible/meaningless name)  is actually a pointer to a pointer, so the signature should be: `void cutting_sentence(struct word **p, char *sen)` Then 1) the place where the `word` in main points can be changed 2) the rest of the code in the function needs to be modified to match the signature

Comment: when calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: regarding: `int size_sen, i, j;`  for readability and understanding, please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `printf("\nNot enaugh memory!");
        return 0;`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  This is easily handled by calling `perror()`;  3) typically returning 0 indicates success.  However, it was not successful when an error occurred.  Suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the local value of the pointer argument passed, you need to change the memory at its target for the caller to discover the location of the allocated memory.  Since you didn't do that, you're trying to free the local variable `word` which is stored on the stack of `main()`.

First thing to fix is not to have a variable identical to the name of a type, that's just evil.

Then change the function prototype to pass a double pointer:

```
void cutting_sentence(struct word **p, char *sen);
```

And remember that where you were using `p` you now need to use `*p` or first assign a local `(word *)` with the address value contained there.

```
void cutting_sentence(struct word **p, char *sen) { //sen is sentence
    int size_sen, i, j;

    size_sen = strlen(sen) + 1; //size of sentence

    *p = (struct word*)malloc(size_sen * sizeof(struct word)); 
    if (*p == NULL) {
        printf("\nNot enaugh memory!");
        return; //void cannot return a value
    }
```

and so on changing every usage of `p` to `*p`.

and then

```
int main() {
    char sentence[1024];
    struct word *words;

    printf("Sentence: ");
    gets(sentence);

    cutting_sentence(&words, sentence);

    if (words != NULL)
       free(words);  //now valid

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I did that. But now I have many errors on every kind of these lines: *p[0].number = 1; or p[j].number = 1; and other examples. It tells me since it's pointer I should use '->', but I don't understand how should I use it since I have '[j]'. Shouldn't then I be able to use '.' ?
Oh and thanks for explaining double pointers!

Comment: `p[0]` becomes `(*p)[0]` or as mentioned you can assign a local `word *` which would be faster than always doing the extra dereference implied by a `word **`.  So for example you could put `struct word **p_ptr)` in the prototype and then have `struct word *p = malloc(...);` and to give it back to the caller `*p_ptr = p;`

Comment: YES! That was it! Thanks a bunch! This makes the code much easier to read and to write. I will work on my pointers as they are really confusing. Code works, and now I understand problems too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more issues than those previously discussed.

[As already pointed out] your first argument should be `struct word **`. But, a simpler way is to eliminate it and change the return type to `struct word *`. This allows the code within the function to be simpler (i.e. no double dereferencing of a pointer)

Although allocating as many word structs as there are characters in the input string will work, that is somewhat unusual.

A better way [more idiomatic, at least] to do this is to use `realloc` inside the loop.

In either case, the array size can be trimmed to only use what it needs via a final `realloc`.

I think that your loop that scans `sen` looking for delimiters is overly complex. Simply using `strtok` in the loop will give the same effect with less complexity.

Also, you're not conveying back a *count* of the number of word. One way is to add an extra element to the array that has a size of zero (e.g. an end-of-list marker)

---

Here's is a refactored version that should help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word {
    char text_word[50];
    unsigned sizee;                     // number of letters of the word
    unsigned number;                    // ordinal number of the word
};

struct word *
cutting_sentence(char *sen)
{                                       // sen is sentence
    int curcnt = 0;
    int maxcnt = 0;
    char *token;
    struct word *word;
    struct word *words;

    while (1) {
        token = strtok(sen," ,.!?\n");
        if (token == NULL)
            break;
        sen = NULL;

        if (curcnt >= maxcnt) {
            maxcnt += 100;
            words = realloc(words,sizeof(struct word) * (maxcnt + 1));
        }

        word = &words[curcnt];
        strcpy(word->text_word,token);
        word->number = curcnt;
        word->sizee = strlen(token);

        ++curcnt;
    }

    words = realloc(words,sizeof(struct word) * (curcnt + 1));

    // set end-of-list
    word = &words[curcnt];
    word->sizee = 0;

    return words;
}

int
main()
{
    char sentence[1024];
    struct word *words;
    struct word *word;

    printf("Sentence: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(sentence,sizeof(sentence),stdin);

    words = cutting_sentence(sentence);

    for (word = words;  word->sizee != 0;  ++word)
        printf("main: number=%u sizee=%u text_word='%s'\n",
            word->number,word->sizee,word->text_word);

    free(words);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No.  You are writing from a fundamentally mistaken premise - please look again at the malloc call and see that it is allocating space for as many structs as there are characters in the input.  That's more than is needed, not less.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yikes, yes you are correct. There is [way] more than enough space. But, _really_? Surely, this can be done more cleanly. And, that should be pointed out to OP [in an explanation at least]. However, I'd edit my explanation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. eliminates redundant code
2. properly checks for errors
3. properly outputs error message (and the text reason the system thinks an error occurred to `stderr`
4. performs the desired functionality
5. properly initializes  the `struct word` pointer
6. properly updates the `struct word` pointer
7. changed `int sizee` to `size_t sizee` because the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`
8. changed `int i` to `unsigned i` because the declaration of the struct field `number` is declared as `unsigned`
9. documents why each header file is included
10. allocates an instance of the `struct word` for every character in the `sentence`  This is 'overkill'.  The most possible amount of words would be if every word was only a single character. So, immediately, the size of the allocated memory could be cut in half.  A loop, counting the word separators would result in the correct amount of allocated memory.  You could easily add that feature.
11. Note the way that the function: `strtok()` is used.  I.E.  initial call before loop, then following calls at end of loop

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fgets(), NULL
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), free()
#include <string.h>  // strlen(),  strtok()


struct word 
{
    char text_word[50];
    size_t sizee; //number of letters of the word
    unsigned number; //ordinal number of the word
};

// notice the `**p` so can access the pointer in `main()` so it can be updated
void cutting_sentence(struct word **p, char *sen) 
{ //sen is sentence
    size_t size_sen = strlen(sen); //size of sentence
    struct word *wordptr = *p;

    wordptr = malloc(size_sen * sizeof(struct word)); 
    if ( !wordptr ) 
    {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    unsigned i = 0;
    char * token = strtok(sen, " ,.!?");
    while( token )
    {
        strcpy( wordptr[i].text_word, token ); 
        wordptr[i].sizee = strlen( token );
        wordptr[i].number = i;

        printf("word:%s\t Length:%lu]tordinal number of the word:%u\n", 
                wordptr[i].text_word, 
                wordptr[i].sizee, 
                wordptr[i].number);

        token = strtok( NULL, " ,.!?");
        i++;
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char sentence[1024];
    struct word *wordArray = NULL;

    printf("Sentence: ");
    if( !fgets(sentence, sizeof( sentence ), stdin ) )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // remove trailing new line
    sentence[ strcspn( sentence, "\n") ]  = '\0';
    cutting_sentence(&wordArray, sentence);

    free( wordArray );  //here is exception triggered

    return 0;
}
```

A typical run of the code results in:

```
Sentence: hello my friend
word:hello   Length:5   ordinal number of the word:0
word:my  Length:2   ordinal number of the word:1
word:friend  Length:6   ordinal number of the word:2
```

Notice that 'short' words result in an uneven output.  You might want to correct that.